# JS events collision

Tags: javascript, jquery, collision

There is a collision while i run a html with inbuilt JS/jQuery. While this action `onclick='window.location="location A"` works for the whole  area and `onclick='action 1'`  should work only for 'Delete' link. The collision is when i press the 'Delete', JS works out the needed action1 first and also (that is *not* needed) redirects into 'location A'. Is it possible to leave the link inside the  area and make this div's JS not reacting on the click to this link?

```
<div class='scraper_item' onclick='window.location="location A"'>
<ul class="scraper_actions1">
    <li><a href="/">Schedule</a></li>
    <li><a class="delete" onclick='action1'>Delete</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

P.S. There should be jQuery script hanging on the 'delete' class. The `preventDefault()` method in jQuery on delete class does not work to prevent moving to `location A`.

Comment: did you checked action1 function to not have a redirect?

Comment: yes, i did. it doesn't redirect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you intend to do it with jQuery:

```
$('div.scraper_item').click(window.location='location A');
$('a.delete').click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    action1();
});
```

`e.stopPropogation()` is what you're looking for, and it means the event we're dealing it will only trigger the current function and not all the events that it's parents are supposed to trigger.

Comment: i have multiple scraper_item with different id's so how can i do in that case?

Answer (score 0):

Returning `false` from a jQuery event callback is the same as calling `e.preventDefault()` **and** `e.stopPropogation()`